# Change returned values of Redux Form Multiselct React Widget

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

My redux form receives as a prop a list categories as follow:

```
[{"id": 1, "name_of_category": "foo"}, {"id": 2, "name_of_category": "bar"}]
```

Using [this example](http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/react-widgets/) from redux form website, I successfully built-in multiselect React Widget into my form, so a user can pick either "foo" or "bar" or both of them. My form also successfully returns a list of names of selected categories, i.e. `["foo", "bar"]` on form submit.

It is all good, but to make my life easier on the back end, I want to return a list of id's of selected categories instead of the list of names.

What can I do for that matter? Do I need to introduce an additional function that will do the job? Or, there is built-in functionality in the React Widget package?

Here is code snippet of my redux form:

```
import React from 'react';
import Multiselect from 'react-widgets/lib/Multiselect'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Form, Button } from 'reactstrap';

import 'react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css'

const required = value => value ? undefined : 'Required';
const renderMultiselect = ({ input, data, valueField, textField }) => 
  let categories = [];
  data.map(category => categories.push(category.name));
  return (
    <Multiselect {...input}
      onBlur={() => input.onBlur()}
      value={input.value || []}
      data={categories}
      valueField={valueField}
      textField={textField}
    />
  )
};

const MyForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, submitting, onSubmit, categories } = props;
  return (
    <Form name="myform" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>      
      <div>
        <label>Categories</label>
        <Field
          name="categories"
          component={renderMultiselect}
          data={categories} />
      </div>
      <Button color="primary" type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'myform',
  enableReinitialize: true
})(MyForm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [DOC](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/multiselect/data?_k=mwxolx):

**[Data Array:](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/multiselect/data?_k=mwxolx)**

> provide an array of possible values for the Multiselect. If an array
>   of objects is provided you should use the valueField and textField
>   props, to specify which object properties comprise the value field
>   (such as an id) and the field used to label the item.

[**valueField:**](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/multiselect/valueField?_k=fpabd7)

> A valueField is required when the value prop is not itself a dataItem.

**[textField:](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/multiselect/textField?_k=0b5y2l)**

> Specify which data item field to display in the Multiselect and
>   selected item.

That means you need to specify the `valueField` and `textField` in case when format of data is:

```
[{}, {}, {}]
```

Write it like this:

```
data = [{"id": 1, "name_of_category": "foo"}, {"id": 2, "name_of_category": "bar"}]

<Multiselect {...input}
   onBlur={() => input.onBlur()}
   value={input.value || []}
   data={data}                        //data will be same data not the name of categories
   valueField="id"                    //value will be id
   textField="name_of_category"       //text will be name of category
/>
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you a lot! I am still learning react world :-)

Comment: glad, it helped you :)